# Validating the integer

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want a Decimal Point in an Integer. If decimal Point is not there it shows Error Message.

Sir, The following code is written in User Control Text Box.The maximum Length given by the user When he access the user control.

The following code is restricts the user to enter the Decimal point after the maximum length.

Please the run the code Sir,

```
   public virtual int MaximumLength { get; set; }
    private void txtCurrency_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        txtCurrency.MaxLength = MaximumLength + 3;
        int dotIndex = txtCurrency.Text.IndexOf('.');
        if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                if (dotIndex != -1 && dotIndex < txtCurrency.SelectionStart && txtCurrency.Text.Substring(dotIndex + 1).Length >= 2)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else if (txtCurrency.Text.Length == MaximumLength)
                {
                    if (e.KeyChar != '.')
                    { e.Handled = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar != '.' || dotIndex != -1 || txtCurrency.Text.Length == 0 || txtCurrency.SelectionStart + 2 < txtCurrency.Text.Length;
            }
        }`enter code here`
```

Comment: great...what you have tried?

Comment: i don't get an idea...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal myValue = 12.4m;
int value = 0;

if (myValue - Math.Round(myValue) != 0)
{
throw new Exception("Has a decimal point");
}
else
{
value = (int)myValue;
}
```

Comment: Sir.., I have a doubt what is that "myValue"?

Comment: shouldn't one use floor instead of round?

Comment: @SztupY it doesn't make a difference (in this scenario)

Comment: seems that the OP is not familiar with some hardcoded code.. but anyway our answer fit for her problem. I hope he get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

```
private void textBox2_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d+.\d{0,1}$");
    if (r.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Okay");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
        e.Handled = true;

    if (e.KeyChar == '.'
        && (textBox2).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1) //Allow one decimal point
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I want in KeyPress Event.But the above code not supported for Decimal Point.I just tried.

Comment: Sir, Your reply is helpful for me sir. sir i want to show my code to you sir. How it is possible sir. I am using a user Control.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please study hard and please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)  `:D`